# If the dependency is a unique snapshot version and install is called, what does maven select?

Tags: maven-2, snapshot

Imagine two projects. The first is the `framework-core` project which is in version `1.1.0` and has several snapshot builds. The other is the `example-business` project which has the following dependency to `framework-core` on the build-iteration number 9.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>framework-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0-20100518.134928-9</version>
</dependency>
```

What happens if `mvn install` is called on the `framework-core`? I found out that the artifact is copied to the folder and is named to `*.1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` (as expected).

This lead me to the assumption that this version is only used if even this `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` version is defined as dependency and not the precise build.

To test something local without deploying it to the maven repository: call `mvn install`, change the dependency to `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` -- and the artifact just installed is used? Or is it possible to overwrite the specific build (with using the `install` lifecycle phase)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using a dependency with a *timestamp version* of a `-SNAPSHOT` - like `-20100518.134928-9` in this case - you **lock** the version and explicitly tell Maven to use **this version**. Even if a new `-SNAPSHOT` is build, the dependency won't get updated, that's the point of a "locked snapshot".

If you want to use the latest `-SNAPSHOT`, declare a dependency on the -SNAPSHOT version to unlock the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>framework-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Changing it manually is not a big deal but the following goals of the [Versions Maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) might help in some situations:

> - [`versions:lock-snapshots`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/lock-snapshots.html)  searches the pom for all -SNAPSHOT
>     versions and replaces them with the
>     current timestamp version of that
>     -SNAPSHOT, e.g. -20090327.172306-4
> - [`versions:unlock-snapshots`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/unlock-snapshots.html) searches the pom for all timestamp
>     locked snapshot versions and replaces
>     them with -SNAPSHOT. 
>     versions:unlock-snapshots

Comment: Thank you again, for explanation. Even the goals of the maven-version-plugin will be helpful! Thanks