# Failed to resolve artifact (snapshot) from my artifactory repository

Tags: maven, artifactory

I've got a local artifactory repository. I've got a dependency in one of my app's pom.xml like the following:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.activequant</groupId>
       <artifactId>activequant-p2</artifactId>
       <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
```

I deployed an activequant-p2-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar to my 'ext-local-snapshot' repository. Artifactory deployed it under org/activequant/activequant-p2/activequant-p2-1.3-20130925.170928.jar . Now when i run 'mvn package':

```
Downloading: http://artifactory.myrepos.local/libs-snapshot/org/activequant/activequant-p2/1.3-SNAPSHOT/activequant-p2-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.activequant:activequant-p2:pom:1.3-SNAPSHOT' in repository snapshots (http://artifactory.myrepos.local/libs-snapshot)

And fails, because http://artifactory.myrepos.local/libs-snapshot/org/activequant/activequant-p2/1.3-SNAPSHOT/activequant-p2-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom does not exist (It's under http://artifactory.myrepos.local/libs-snapshot/org/activequant/activequant-p2/1.3-SNAPSHOT/activequant-p2-1.3-20130925.170928.pom).

How should i deploy the artifact in my artifactory or configure my pom.xml to fix this problem?

Looked at this: [Maven: Why is the -SNAPSHOT suffix missing from artifact file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869962/maven-why-is-the-snapshot-suffix-missing-from-artifact-file-name)  , which seems like the problem, but i'm using maven3 on the client side, so there's no 'uniqueVersion' tag at all. I tried changing the "Maven Snapshot Version Behavior" setting for my repository, but that does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason my local maven repository was dirty (no snapshot timestamps in metadata file downloaded). Running maven did no substitute the metadata, so i deleted my org/activequant/activequant-p2 manually from my local repos and all went ok.