# maven downloads snapshots with timestamp

Tags: java, maven, snapshot

On a Redhat system running maven 3.0.3, certain artifacts are being downloaded with the timestamp instead of the `-SNAPSHOT.jar` ending.

```
a-2.3.0-20140206.210030-51.jar
b-2.3.0-20140206.205829-51.jar
```

etc.

However, on a Ubuntu system running maven 3.0.3, the same downloaded artifacts have the `-SNAPSHOT.jar` ending.

```
a-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
b-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The settings.xml files are identical. The `~/.m2/repository` has been blow away. The repo is identical.

What am I missing?

Comment: there must be one with just SNAPSHOT in your local cache, are you sure all of them are timestamped ?

Comment: I think duplicated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869962/maven-why-is-the-snapshot-suffix-missing-from-artifact-file-name

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869962/maven-why-is-the-snapshot-suffix-missing-from-artifact-file-name and the solution works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: Why is the -SNAPSHOT suffix missing from artifact file name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869962/maven-why-is-the-snapshot-suffix-missing-from-artifact-file-name)